# Angular UI_ROUTER Could not resolve 'newUser' from state 'login'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I trying to use `ui.routing` but using `stateProvider` I get error : `Could not resolve 'newUser' from state 'login'`.
Here is my config:

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
    <section id="mainBody">
        <div class="continer">
            <div>
                <a ui-sref="main">Header</a>
                <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
                <a ui-sref="list2">List2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ui-view></div>
            <div>Footer</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [, 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

mainApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: 'login',
        templateUrl: '../../pages/login.html'
    });
}]);
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="loginApp">
<body>
    <section id="form">
        <!--form-->
        <div class="container login-user">
            <div class="row">
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-loginUser btn-default col-xs-12 col-sm-2" ui-sref="existingUser">Existing user</a>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-loginUser btn-default col-xs-12 col-sm-2" ui-sref="newUser">New user</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ui-view="userInfo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.js**

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp', ['ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

loginApp.config(['stateProvider', function (stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('existingUser', {
            views: {
                "userInfo": {
                    url: 'existinguser',
                    templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/existingUserForm.html',
                    controller: 'existingUserCtrlr'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('newUser', {
            views: {
                "userInfo": {
                    url: 'newUser',
                    templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/newUserForm.html',
                    controller: 'newUserCtrlr'
                }
            }
        });
}]);
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

`loginApp` and `mainApp` are two different modules. You cant go to `newUser` from `login` because `login` is defined on `mainApp`. While other two routes are defined on `loginApp`. Define all routes on same module.

Comment: so, if I want to make all app single page, I need to define all routes in one place/module? Not possible to separate in files?

Comment: Yes routes are defined on one module.

Comment: If you want to link out of your app, please use


`<a href="some/url" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">A link outside of the app</a>`

Comment: I tried that, but if I move route to one module. And try open template inside template [open login.html and in its ui-view="userInfo" open another ] everything disappears.